# What is the protocol for email notes?

Tags: macos, email, sync

What is the protocol for email notes?

I have an email account associated with my domain and web server. When I added this email to "internet accounts" within my macbook preferences, it had an option to use notes with it. I'm wondering where those notes are synced to? I haven an android phone and if it's possible to have them synced between my phone and my MacBookPro then that would be awesome.

You'll see in the picture below what I mean when I say that I have the option to sync notes with my private email for my domain.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have an IMAP server it will create a folder called 'Notes' and sync all the notes to that folder. You can then browse them with any IMAP client.

Probably me.com also has a feature which supports this and it might even sync with Exchange notes. It probably won't work for POP3.

Comment: Okay, I do have an imap server. That must be why. I'm going to dig for a android client that I can use to sync with these as a test. If anyone knows of any, please let me know.